# MtGox withdrawal transaction not in blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mtgox

I just withdrew some BTC from Mt Gox to address 1Mvk4YAtKZAP43wEhZ6ZQrTzLZwZzPxtTJ, transaction id 3dfa979af56ff061efbceed0dd7c9dc9fd8c774249544018f6bbf646323ff03b, but didn't receive the coins and the transaction isn't in the chain.  Should I be worried?

Comment: Hmm - yeah, I made a withdrawal a few hrs ago and its not showing - get a bit concerned when instant transactions aren't instant :D Sounds like it is not unusual, so I won't hit the panic button yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Mt.gox has tendency to delay BTC withdrawals from time to time. Happened to me couple of days ago too. I tried to withdraw 1.8 BTC to another address but the transaction didn't show up in the block chain. Eventually it did, something like 12 hours later. I heard other people have waited for days for their withdrawal to complete.

I recommend to open a ticket just in case, but realize that this is not uncommon.
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks @BabyPuncher, feeling a little better - fingers crossed! :)

Comment: The transaction has now appeared in the blockchain, so about 5 hours delay.  Whew!